# Evaluate $\oint_{|z|=1}z(z+1)cosh\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\oint_{|z|=1}z(z+1)cosh\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$$ The direction is counter clockwise.

I was trying to use the residue theorem. So basically I tried to evaluate $$z(z+1) $$ at $z=0$. But this qustion is worth 10 marks so I assume the solution can't be that simple. Could someone at least guide me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: The essential problem is the singularity (*what* type of singularity?) of $\cosh(1/z)$ at $z=0$.

Comment: you mean simple pole etc? So do I just differentiate 1/z? But then I can't still evaluate that at z=0

Comment: Isn't a simple pole (and *essential* is important).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the Laurent series of $\cosh(1/z)$ is
$$\cosh\frac1z=\frac12(\exp(1/z)+\exp(-1/z))=\cdots$$

Comment: ok so I think I've made some progress $$cosh(1/z)=\sum_{n=0}\frac{1}{2n!z^{2n}}$$ So now I can multiply this series by z and z+1 and find the coefficient for -1th power. Is that it?

Comment: Ok I've found a similar problem with its solution. I'll let you know if I find an answer for this question

Comment: @Alp, yes, is the standard procedure with essential singularities.

Comment: ok so this is what I have so far $$z(z+1)cosh(1/z)=(z^2+z)\sum_{n=0}\frac{1}{2n!z^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}\frac{1}{2n!z^{2n-2}}+\sum_{n=0}\frac{1}{2n!z^{2n-1}}$$ but z^-1 does not exist for the first term. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Alp, nothing. You are simply separating even index and odd index summands.

Comment: so the answer is $$\pi i$$ ???

Comment: @Alp, according to my calculations, the residue is $1/2$ and the integral is $\pi i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, sir! Appreciated!